# How to select an option from a dropdown list in one webform and view the result in a gridview in another webform?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

this is my project, i am using visual studio 2010 and my coding language is vb. I am new to this and it will be safe to say that i don't know much of it yet.

I have a login page where the head of department enters his detail(employee number, employee name), selects his department and submits the information to see the result in other web form i.e all the employees that are under his department out of all the employees working for the company.

Because i don't know the code, i am getting all the employees of every department in the gridview instead of getting the employees for the department that was selected from the dropdown list.

### here is my code for the first page

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="login.aspx.vb" Inherits="login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.style1
{
width: 1179px;
height: 106px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<br />
<img alt="iocl" class="style1" src="Images/materials_hrd.bmp" /><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</div>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Employee Name"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Employee_Number" runat="server" Text="Employee Number"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
-<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Department"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>Information Systems</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Human Resources</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Resource &amp; Development</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Finance</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Pipelines</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Marketing</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### And this is the second page's code

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="HODLogin.aspx.vb" Inherits="HODLogin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.style1
{
width: 1259px;
height: 105px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<br />
<br />
<img alt="iocl" class="style1" src="Images/materials_hrd.bmp" /><br />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="195px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
Width="1125px">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Employee Number" HeaderText="Employee Number" 
SortExpression="Employee Number" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Employee Name" HeaderText="Employee Name" 
SortExpression="Employee Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" 
SortExpression="Department" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Grade" HeaderText="Grade" SortExpression="Grade" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />

</Columns>
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString11 %>" 
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString11.ProviderName %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [employee database]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblempno" runat="server" 
Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
<br />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me the process and the code and also where to put it, i am not very familiar with all this. Its kind of an emergency.

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the selected item text in onw variable, like the below:

```
dim selText as string = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
```

and on the click of submit button, perform your required tasks and then redirect page to another page along with the department name. Like the below code:

```
 Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?department=" + selText)
```

and on the second page i.e. Page2.aspx, just receive this value in query string, using below code.. wherever it is necessary either on page load or at your required place.

```
 If Request.QueryString("department") <> Nothing Then
  dim departmt as string = Request.QueryString("department")
 End If
```

And use the above variable's value in your database query and get the related data to the department selected in the previous form.

I hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also save selected item text in Session. Afterward you can get this value from any page in your project:

```
Session("department") = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
```

You also can use this value directly in your SqlDataSource on Page2:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString11 %>" 
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString11.ProviderName %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [employee database] WHERE Department LIKE @depart">
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="%" Name="depart" SessionField="user" 
            Type="string" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```